# Why can I not connect to my localhost database server?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I can access localhost/phpmyadmin/ through my browser and create tables, insert tuples, etc but I can't connect to it in PHP code. Here's what I got:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '');
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
        . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo 'Success';
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

and i have an HTML form somewhere else with an action attribute that runs the above code. But whenever I test my code, it returns an Error 500. I won't tell me anything more specific, even though I included error reporting! Why?

Comment: Your `mysqli` object is `$conn`, but you call `close()` on `$mysqli`, which is undeclared. This is most likely the culprit.

Comment: Developing with disabled error reporting is really very bad idea. If you have a syntax error in your script, the `error_reporting` function won't be called obviously, so it won't enable it. You should always enable it in `php.ini`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have error in creating connection:
`mysqli` is not a function, you need to use `mysqli_connect`

```
$conn = new mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); // here is change
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
        . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo 'Success'
$conn->close(); // close connection using connection resource
?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_connect` is just an alias for the `mysqli` constructor http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php